# get the pattern before a given word

Tags: java, regex

below is my text :

```
12,7 C84921797-6 Provisoirement, 848,80 smth
```

i want to extract the value `848,80` with the float pattern : `[-+]?[0-9]*\\,?[0-9]+`
but the code i am using extracts only the first value matching the pattern which is `12,7`
this is my method :

```
String display(String pattern , String result){

    String value= null
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);//compiles the pattern
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(result);//check if the result contains the pattern
    if(matcher.find()) {
        //get the first value found corresponding to the pattern 
        value = matcher.group(0) 
    }

    return value
}
```

when i call this method :

```
String val=display("[-+]?[0-9]*\\,?[0-9]+" ," 12,7 C84921797-6 Provisoirement, 848,80 smth" )
println("val---"+val)
```

OUTPUT :

```
val---12,7
```

i want to use the word `smth` after the value to extract the correct value how can i proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `smth` in your regex after part you are interested in. Just place interesting part in parenthesis to create group and refer to part matched by this group via Matchers `group(id)` method like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([-+]?[0-9]*\\,?[0-9]+)\\s+smth");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(result);
if(matcher.find())
{
    value = matcher.group(1); //get the first value found corresponding to the pattern 
}
```

---

Other method would be using [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) to test if after part you are interested in exists `smth`. So your regex could look like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[-+]?[0-9]*\\,?[0-9]+(?=\\s+smth)");
```

Thanks to fact that look-ahead is zero-length it will not be included in match so you can use `group(0)` or simpler `group()` from Matcher to get result you want.

Comment: thank you for your answer , but i wanted to extract only the value 848,80 not the word smth with it

Comment: @manu That is exactly how my answer works. In case of first version you just read value from group 1 (the numeric part), and in case of version two `smtg` is not included in match.

Comment: and if i don't have a space instead it could be like this  "848,80 ,smth" or "848,80 : smth" or "848,80 // -smth"  should i replace the "\\s+"  with "?+" ?

Comment: @manu Well, you can try to add other characters which could appear between `848,80` and `smth`, so instead of `\\s+` try maybe `[\\s\\-:,/]+`.

Answer (score 0):

```
([\\d\\,]+) smth
```

With this **$1** matches the float number you wanted

Answer (score 0):

If you always have `smth` (note one whitespace) after your number representation, try this:

```
String input = "12,7 C84921797-6 Provisoirement, 848,80 smth";
//                            | optional sign
//                            |   | number 1st part
//                            |   |   | optional comma, more digits part
//                            |   |   |       | lookahead for " smth"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[-+]?\\d+(,\\d+)*(?=\\ssmth)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found --> " + m.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
Found --> 848,80
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , it could not be a space between the value i want to extract and the word ( 848,80 : smth ) or ( 848,80 _ smth )in this case how do i replace the pattern ? with "[-+]?\\d+(,\\d+)*(?=\?smth)"      ?

Comment: @manu unfortunately "lookarounds" don't work with quantifiers. See Pshemo's answer to capture the number in a group. You can easily adapt the `\\s+` part to capture more than just spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s+\\d+,\\d+");
```

http://fiddle.re/n17np